# Issues at production: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: next.js, vercel, trpc

I've been trying to deploy my NextJs app but I keep encountering the following error. The deployment is successful but when I try to log in:

```
Error al analizar la respuesta JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getServerSideUser (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/611.js:1:33642)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Navbar (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/611.js:1:26862)
```

This is where the error began:

```
import { User } from '../payload-types'
import { ReadonlyRequestCookies } from 'next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/request-cookies'
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export const getServerSideUser = async (
  cookies: NextRequest['cookies'] | ReadonlyRequestCookies
) => {
  const token = cookies.get('payload-token')?.value

  const meRes = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/users/me`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
      },
    }
  )
  const responseText = await meRes.text();
  console.log('API Response:', responseText);
  
  try {
    const { user } = JSON.parse(responseText);
    return { user };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al analizar la respuesta JSON:', error);
    return { user: null };
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong but I realized that I'm getting a HTML as a response from the API. Also, this error only happens to me in prodction, on development works fine. Any particular solutions to work around this issues?

If it helps, here's the link so you can try and see the error in the console.
https://digitalhippo-jade.vercel.app